# Unable to research FreeText (reporting) applications

Tags: .net, formatting, freetext

I am writing an class library that will format free text. The free text I receive is not completely random, there are categories with basic patterns and additional meta data with criteria (eg Season, Country) to help produce the expected output.

Here is an example of freetext input and the formatted output text:

[image]

As you can see below I have a few idea's on how I'm going to do it - Replacing Keywords, Removing Keywords, using meta data criteria to add conditions and even some scribbled out idea's about delimiting text blocks and concatenating them together in a special order:

[image]

Before I start writing tests and coding, I am doing market research to try find any other application that formats free-text?

As per https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/ I am not after shopping or buying recommendations. I am after the knowledge of any other product on the market that formats free-text to confirm I'm not redesigning the wheel, gain idea's, etc.

Even providing me with the correct google term to find Free-Text Formatting Engines I would accept as an answer, all the results come up with:

**Full Text - SQL

Text Free - SMS

Free Text - Editors**

Are there any Free-Text formatting applications? or scripting tools like the opposite of those website plagiarism generators that fine-tune specific content based on rules?